# "column-width" doesn't apply to my code

Tags: html, css

So I'm new to web-oriented coding and learning HTML/CSSfrom a book, I've come to the chapter about creating columns and using their properties.

I'm testing my code on a 3-pages website and when it came to editing the text into columns I am stuck for how to set column-witdh.

Here is the code I used and the css

```css
section {
  column-count: 3;
  column-width: 3em;
}
```

```html
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title> Test colonne</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css_colonne.css">
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone see what's wrong (it doesn't work either with -moz-column-width)

Column division works but it never works

Comment: I see 3 columns. https://jsfiddle.net/nq6rk2e5/

Comment: Me too but can't change the width

Comment: `column-count` takes precedence over the `column-width`

Answer (score 0):

> The column-width CSS property specifies the **minimum** column width.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-width

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/nq6rk2e5/2/)

```
.wrapper {
  width: 9em;
}
section {
    column-count: 3;
}
```

Instead of explicitly setting column width, use a container element.

Comment: Thanks ! Isn't <secton> a container element ?

Comment: In this case it's a column. It might be better for you to make `<section>` a container and add divs inside that.